# How can i align the text to right side in Textbox in Javascript.... ??? By default it is left-align

Tags: javascript, textbox, alignment

My problem is that i couldn't align the text in the textbox from the right side...

Generally this kind of align are used in Calculator... where digits are align from the right side...

i want to do this in HTML by using javascript....

Comment: use css or style tag in html with `text-align: right`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I right-align a text box?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049960/how-can-i-right-align-a-text-box)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<input type="text" style="text-align: right" />`

should work.

Other interesting attributes are: direction:rtl;unicode-bidi:bidi-override;