# How can I right-align a text box?

Tags: html, css, textarea

In php when we type a word in a textarea it is shown at the top-left of the textarea.
I want the text to appear at the top-right when the user beings typing a word. 
How can I achieve this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about setting `text-align: right`?

[Example.](http://jsfiddle.net/HrUxU/)

Answer (score 0):

Either set `text-align:right;` as lonesomeday wrote or set `direction` to `rtl`. [See this example.](http://jsfiddle.net/pqhw4/)